# How can I use three conditions in a single cell? (IF+AND)

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

Say I have a B60 and C60 cells which are both checkbox.
I only need three results,

1. If B60 is true
2. If B60 isn't true.
3. If B60 and C60 are true.

I tried using

```
=IF(B60=TRUE,"B60 is true",AND(C60=TRUE,"Both B60 and C60 are true")
```

how can i fix this

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=IF((B60=TRUE)*(C60=TRUE), "Both B60 and C60 are true",
 IF(B60=TRUE, "B60 is true", "B60 isn't true"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `CHOOSE`:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A1:A),CHOOSE(B1:B+C1:C*B1:B+1,"B is false", "B is true", "B&C are true"),""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use:

=IF(AND (C60=FALSE, B60=TRUE),"B60 is true", IF(AND (C60=TRUE, B60=TRUE), "Both B60 and C60 are true", ""))

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Explain:

1. If B60 is true
2. If B60 isn't true.
3. If B60 and C60 are true.

is equal:

1. only B60 is true (C60 is false) `"B60 is true"`
2. both B60 and C60 are true => `"Both B60 and C60 are true"`

so we create 2 conditions:

1. AND (C60=FALSE, B60=TRUE)
2. AND (C60=TRUE, B60=TRUE)